# Pop up Alerts in moss 2010 Intranet site

Tags: sharepoint-2010

I need to create  alerts to group/all employees in my site.To my site home page basing on the data pushed into "custome list" by administrator in moss 2010 intranet site.So can any one suggest steps to acheive this.Hoping quick replys...

Answer (score 0):

Create a simple workflow using SharePoint designer and send out alerts/notification emails to the users in the group when something happens in your list (like a costume worth more than 100 bucks is entered etc..). You can trigger this notifications workflow in many scenarios.

See this [link](http://anyrest.wordpress.com/2010/11/03/step-by-step-guide-in-developing-your-own-workflow-in-sharepoint-2010/).
Check out [this](http://www.bing.com/videos/watch/video/getting-started-sharepoint-2010-creating-workflows-with-sharepoint-designer/10ts7flgd) video on how to create workflows using designer.

Having said that, if you need a pop-up or a message box to appear when a user visits the site (and ofcourse when something changed on your list) then you have to write code in the load event of the page/any web part on the page  to display popup. SharePoint 2010 has Javascript API which makes it easy for you to display pop-up or you can do this totally in the code.